# Lambda errors not being caught by try/catch blocks or error handler

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to log errors in an alexa skill that runs in a Lambda function, but no matter what I try, errors somehow get through my `try/catch` blocks without being logged.

This is my `index.js`:

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

try {
  const handlers = require('./handlers');

  const wrappedHandlers = handlers.map(handler => ({
    ...handler,
    async handle(handlerInput) {
      try {
        console.log(`Running handler ${handler.name}`, JSON.stringify(handlerInput, null, 2));
        const response = await handler.handle(handlerInput);
        console.log(`Successfully ran handler ${handler.name}`, JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
        return response;
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(`Failed to run handler ${handler.name}`, error.stack);
        throw error;
      }
    },
  }));

  exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders
    .custom()
    .addRequestHandlers(...wrappedHandlers)
    .addErrorHandlers(require('./handlers/error'))
    .lambda();
} catch(error) {
  console.log('Fatal initialization error', error);
  exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders
    .custom()
    .addRequestHandlers({
      canHandle() { return true; },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(`Initialization error`, error.stack);
      },
    })
    .lambda();
}
```

The top-level `try/catch` should catch any errors thrown during `require('./handlers')`. I've observed this working in the past catching syntax errors in my handlers.

I'm also wrapping every handler's `handle` function in a `try/catch` (see `wrappedHandlers`). My error handler also logs any errors it sees:

```
// handlers/error.js
module.exports = {
  canHandle() { return true; },

  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error handled: ${error.stack}`);

    // During tests, include the error in the response
    if(process.env['NODE_ENV'] === 'test') {
      const { attributesManager } = handlerInput;
      const sessionAttributes = attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
      sessionAttributes.error = error;
      attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes);
    }

    const message = error && error.speachMessage || `Sorry, I can't understand the command. Please say again. ${error.stack}`;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(message)
      .reprompt(message)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

Despite all of this, the Alexa simulator is spitting out `[Error]: An unexpected error occurred.`, but the cloudwatch logs don't contain any errors or failed requests. How is this possible?

Comment: `speachMessage` -> `speechMessage`?

Comment: That is a typo, but it's consistent throughout, so I don't think it's causing the issue. Though it would make sense that an error being thrown in the error handler would cause this issue so I'll test that a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this problem and I've got a function which is throwing with a lambda 502 bad gateway, the cloudwatch log entry contains

```
Invoke Error {"errorType":"UnauthorizedError","errorMessage":"Forbidden","name":"UnauthorizedError","stack":["UnauthorizedError: Forbidden"," at /var/task/ApiServerClass.js:57:27"," at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"," at async module.exports.me (/var/task/ApiServerClass.js:68:43)"," at async module.exports.run (/var/task/ApplicationClass.js:42:22)"]}
```

But wrapped around that entire function is a `try/catch`

It's as if throwing an exception immediately causes lambda to quit and all your exception handling is ignored. But when running local tests through mocha. The exceptions are respected